# Broken Pipe in Django dev server - What does this actually mean?

Tags: django

I can't quite figure out a pattern to why/when I see it.  Cheers.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace, or the full error message?

Comment: Some times that error means the browser closed the connection, it could happen if the user changed to another page before the current one finishes loading.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Along with some other research I've discovered something strange, but useful - if I use Firefox rather than Chrome, whilst I'm seeing the broken pipe error on my django dev server console, I'm seeing a proper Django error message in my browser window. Much less mysterious, and much less useful! Thanks.

Comment: Hey, so, welcome to stack overflow. You can comment on questions and answers, and should do that instead of making a new answer. You can also mark answers as correct, and vote them up once they work for you. (and are encouraged to).

Anyway, cheers, and I hope you really enjoy working with Django

Comment: Okay picked an answer, but none of them were really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "pipe" it means the TCP connection between the server and the browser.  By "broken" it means closed.

You'll see broken pipes when somebody closes their browser window, hits stop, or sometimes just from timing out because something else breaks the connection.

The confusing thing is that the python process likely won't notice that the connection is closed until it tries to write to it, which could be well after the connection closes.

Answer (score 2):

I get this error when a browser closes a connection (it can time out, or can be manually closed).  Normally it happens when I send too many connections to runserver at once (i.e. I'm serving static media, and loading a heavy page for the first time).

Django's runserver should not be used in production, and it doesn't handle concurrent connections with any grace.  If this happens a lot, you can consider using something like django_cpserver or gunicorn in development, but you don't get as much debug information out of them in the console.